# send calendar event/invite with eventkit

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I doubt it is possible, but figure I should ask... is it possible to send a calendar event/invite to another user's iphone if you have their email address or phone number?

I don't see anything in the documentation.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Nope. The specs on the app changed so I never pursued it further.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least be able to create an email attachment which is an [ics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) file and send it to someone. A similar approach for contacts does work; I haven't tried it for events though. If this approach is acceptable I'd use an in-app mail view controller, attach a simple .ics file and send it to yourself. You'll quickly see if it works, plus whether it fits with your use-case.